# 99.9% returns false in If Statement

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have an if statement and i cannot get a grip where I may have went wrong. everytime the results is 99.9% it is returning as "False", whereas it should within range and should result to "Awesome"

```
99.6    Good!
99.7    Great
99.8    Cool!
99.9    Super!
100     Prima!!
```

there is definitely something wrong with my statement.

```
=if(K2=100%,$M$5,if(K2>=99.9%,$M$4,if(K2>=99.8%,$M$3,if(K2>=99.7%,$M$2,if(K2>=99.6%,$M$1)))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TX49RPATclsWo7yUeJgUQ1x4CdBKAdniyxfX2DaWZLQ/edit?usp=sharing

[Added a photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uTJ0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Expected output seems to be "Super!", because K2 is the first condition which matchs, `99.9 >= 99.9%`, which is same as `99.9 >= 0.999`.

Your bug is that `%`, it means `/100`. **99.9% is same as 0.999**.

To fix: add `%` to the column with numbers, which is same as changing the numbers to be 0.996...1, or remove it from the formula.

Comment: Hi @hyde, thank you so much, I have added a photo to the original question, I wanted that if the percentage rounds up or down, it should be able to follow the results

Comment: @hamster Your screenshot seems to be from different situation than what you ask about. That's a bit confusing, better to not have contradictory stuff in the question.

Comment: apologies for that, I think that the initial issue got fixed by the solution you provided. the other issue I was having, when I was trying to round up the percentages, sometimes if it's 99.96%, it will round up to 100%, is there a way where it would say Prima (when rounded up) rather than showing "Super"?

Comment: @hamster The way this site works is, if you have a new question, ask a new question. Also reading through the help section of the site (at the bottom of the page) might be good idea before asking a lot of questions.